# Don't generate blocks without values (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have back-end code

here is code

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult QuestionBlocks()
    {
        var _id = TempData["ID"];

        var questBlock = db.QuestionBlocks
            .Where(x => x.Interview_Id == (int?) _id)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ID = x.Block_ID,
                Question1 = x.Question1,
                Question2 = x.Question2,
                Question3 = x.Question3,
                Question4 = x.Question4,
                Question5 = x.Question5,
                Question6 = x.Question6,
                Question7 = x.Question7,
                Question8 = x.Question8,
                Question9 = x.Question9,
                Question10 = x.Question10,

            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(questBlock, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

But some of Questions may be without values.

Here on front-end I display it on View

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    question_block();
});
function question_block() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Interwier")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var email = result;
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var question =
                    '<div class="activeQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question1 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question2 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question3 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question4 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question5 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question6 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question7 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question8 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question9 +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                        email[i].Question10 +
                        '</div>';
                $("#questions").append(question);
                $('.hiddenQue:empty').hide();
```

Now I hide it via `$('.hiddenQue:empty').hide();` but it's not what I want, I need to not generate divs if it has not value.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use if condition, inside `for` loop to check if it has question or not. it will work  for you.

```
 <script>
       question_block();

       function question_block() {
           $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Home")',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'json',
               processData: false,
               success: function (result) {
                   var email = result;
                   for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                       var question = "";
                       for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                           var getQ = email[i]["Question" + j];
                           if (getQ) {
                               question += '<div class="activeQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' +
                                                getQ +
                                        '</div>';
                           }
                       }
                       if (question != "") {
                           $("#questions").append(question);
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: Okay, thank's

Also I can achieve it via `$('.hiddenQue:empty').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this !!!

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    question_block();
    });
    function question_block() {
     $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Interwier")',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     processData: false,
     success: function(result) {
        var email = result;

        for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
     var question='';
     var Question1='';
     var Question2='';
     var Question3='';
     var Question4='';
     var Question5='';
     var Question6='';
     var Question7='';
     var Question8='';
     var Question9='';

     email[i].Question1==''?Question1='':Question1='<div class="activeQue" 
                   style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left:  
          50%;transform:     translate(-50%, -50%);">' +email[i].Question1 +
                    '</div>'
       question=question+Question1
       //Do this for all question

            $("#questions").append(question);
            //$('.hiddenQue:empty').hide();
```